# Deregister target from application load balancer with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, load-balancing

I'm trying to deregister target machine from AWS application load balancer before deployment and add it back after. I think the way to do it is module `elb_target_group` but I don't know how to write elb_target_group to have all targets without the machine that is under deployment.

For example

```
elb_target_group:
    name: Api
    protocol: http
    port: 9000
    vpc_id: vpc-1
    state: present
    region: eu-central-1
    targets:
      - Id: i-1111111111
        Port: 9000
      - Id: i-2222222222
        Port: 9000
```

If I wanted to deregister target `i-1111111111` I would have to have all other targets and I don't know where to get them.

In this case

```
    targets:
      - Id: i-2222222222
        Port: 9000
```

PS target instance id is not in result of `elb_target_group_facts` so it does not help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found that there is new module planned for ansible 2.5 called `elb_target` that does exactly this.

You can find it in this PR
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/26483
Then I just added it to `/library` folder in my project and it works fine